# Question about late-onset Conduct Disorder and Antisocial Personality Disorder

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive

If Conduct Disorder started at 15, 16 or 17 and if that behavior persists in adulthood, would that person be diagnosed with Antisocial Personality Disorder? With new diagnostic DSM-5 model for Antisocial Personality Disorder, would it be different?